# mongock @BeforeExecution is not executed

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongock

I need to initialize `admin` from env variables, but @BeforeExecution method is not launched, execution directly starts in `initAdmin` method. Any suggestions?

```
@ChangeUnit(id = "init", order = "001", author = "me")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class InitChangeLog {

  private final MyService service;
  private final MongoTemplate template;
  private final ConfigurableEnvironment env;

  private String admin;

  @BeforeExecution
  private void setAdmin() {
    this.admin = env.getProperty("admin");
  }

  @Execution
  public void initAdmin() {
    service.create(...);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see multiple errors there that can be the reason of your issue:

1. @Component shouldn't be used for a changeUnit. The way Mongock retrieves the changeUnits is by specifying the packages or directly the class. You can see it in the [documentation](https://docs.mongock.io/v5/get-started/index.html#7--build-the-runner)
2. Mongock offers two ways to inject your beans, in the constructor and directly in the method. Please see [this section in the documentation](https://docs.mongock.io/v5/features/custom-injections/index.html#how-to-use-a-custom-bean-in-changeunit) for more information
3. @BeforeExecution shouldn't be private.

Try correcting those points and I am confident it will work just fine :)

Comment: You're welcome!! Could you vote the answer as useful, so other users can learn from it? :)